# imageview OutOfMemoryError exception: trying to cache resized images to avoid exception

Tags: android, caching, imageview, out-of-memory

I have read all of the outofmemoryerror threads and I understand that I am trying to resize to mamny images. I am storing these images on my server at a max size of 250x250. I am trying to load them in a list. I have implemented a cache system and it works great. The problem is that I am caching the image size from the server and im still doing the resize each time i pull it from the cache.

I want to resize the image before I put it into the cache. I am using xml to resize the image in the list.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img_user" android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="100dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/noimgsmall"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

My list adapter is where I put the image into the cache. The problem is that I do not know at this point the size of the imageview.

```
Drawable cachedImage = null;
                cachedImage = imageLoader.loadImage(
                        store.getLogoUrl(),
                        new ImageThreadLoader.ImageLoadedListener() {
                            public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageBitmap) {
                                View itemView = parent.getChildAt(position -
                                        ((ListView) parent).getFirstVisiblePosition());
                                if (itemView == null) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                ImageView img = (ImageView)
                                itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
                                if (img == null) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                img.setImageDrawable(imageBitmap);
                            }
                        }
                );
                logoImageView.setImageDrawable(cachedImage);
```

How can I figure out the size of the image to cache?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was resizing the images to the actual scaled sizes and then caching. No more memory problems. Aviod re-sizing as must as you can in a listview.